# Find and print the length of the longest line in multiple files?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

In my folder, I have 2000 files, which are labeled A0001-A2000. In the second line of each file, there is a long (it should be the longest) line of characters. I would like to print all the file names with the length of the second line in one output.

so the output will look something like

```
A0001 231
A0002 123
A0003 56
```

If it is helpful I already have a code that will print the longest line of a file, but I am not tied to using awk if there is an easier way.

```
$ awk '{print length}' A0001.txt |sort -nr|head -1
231
```

Comment: Please clarify if you want to print the longest line from each file regardless of its line number or line number 2 from each file regardless of its length or something else. Your subject says `Find and print the length of the longest line` while your text says `print all the file names with the length of the second line` which elsewhere you say **should** be the longest so it's not clear what you want output if/when the 2nd line isnt the longest.

Comment: So for the work I am doing the longest line and the second line should be equal. I can explain if its necessary but its more biology/bioinformatics

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==2{print FILENAME,length; nextfile}' *
```

The glob expands to all files in the directory, and when Awk reaches the 2nd line it prints the filename and its length and skips to the next file. This `nextfile` is optional and for performance only.

If there may be non-regular files in the directory, use Find so that Awk does not choke:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec awk 'FNR==2{print FILENAME,length; nextfile}' {} +
```

`-maxdepth 1` makes find non-recursive (i.e. it does not look into subdirectories). You can also use `-prune` if `-maxdepth` is not available.

Answer (score 4):

If the max line *might not* be line 2, you can do:

- with GNU awk

  ```bsh
  gawk '
      BEGINFILE {max = -1} 
      length > max {max = length} 
      ENDFILE {print FILENAME, max}
  ' *
  ```
- with non-GNU awk

  ```bsh
  awk '
      FNR == 1 {
          if (filename != "") print filename, max
          filename = FILENAME
          max = -1
      }
      length > max {max = length}
      END {print filename, max}
  ' *
  ```

Comment: Could also print FNR to tell which line was longest. Or check it against the assumed 2 and scream if it's some other.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the GNU wc should do the job.

```
wc -L A*
```

- Assuming files don't choke the command line. In that scenario you can use a for loop or a find command.